# "Fetching JS Bundle" Monstrously Slow

Tags: android, react-native

I've been trying to create basic react-native Android apps on my Windows machine for some time now. Even when deploying the most basic "Welcome to React Native" app, I experience extremely long wait times while my emulator prints: "Fetching JS Bundles". These times are well past 4 minutes.

[image]

I've tried a variety of emulators, enabled HAXM, enabled gradle, tried the Intel_x64, Intel_x86, Google APIs for x64 / x86 and still the slow-down.

Any suggestions on what else I can try?

Comment: How long does it take on a real device?

Comment: @JeanRegisser also over 4 minutes on real device...

Comment: Added to the confusion, for both the emulator and the device the screen doesn't refresh to reflect code changes.

Comment: Do you have remote debugging turned on?  I've experienced really long load times with remote debugging that go away once I turn it off.  This problem was much worse when using the Android emulator compared to the iOS emulator.

Comment: Same issue here. Regarding things not loading, there seems to be a lot of things talking about that on their issues pages. Specifically this one that's new https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10689

Comment: Wait, what version of python, node and npm do you have installed? I'm starting to wonder if that may have an affect.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I solved this by NOT using adb to reverse my TCP port 8081.</strike>

UPDATE 2: I thought that I solved this by using my public IP/host name, but it turns out that `react-native run-android` re-creates the `adb reverse` every time you execute it. See UPDATE 1 at the bottom for relevant links.

ORIGINAL:

When I originally setup my machine for React Native, I ran the following command to let the React app communicate with the React Packager: `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`. I observed that every time I ran `react-native run-android`, my emulator would stay stuck on "Fetching JS Bundle for a long time".

To fix the problem with the emulator on Windows:

1. Access the Developer Menu (in-app, in the emulator) by simulating a device shake. Open `Additional Tools -> Accelerometer` and press Play on the bottom of the window, beneath `Recorded data: shake`.
2. Click `Dev Settings` (last menu item).
3. Click `Debug server host & port for device` and set the value to the `public IP/Name:Port` of my PC on the network. (e.g. `devpc.mynet.local:8081` or `192.168.1.99:8081`).
4. Close the react app.
5. Run `adb reverse --remove-all` to undo my previous `adb reverse tcp:8081...` command.
6. Restart everything from my pc by running `react-native run-android`. Observe that this time, the `Fetching JS Bundle` step executes almost immediately.

I just discovered this workaround for my own environment. I have not tried it on any actual devices. Furthermore, I wonder if there is a way to specify this from code so that it works correctly the first time (instead of having to specify the public IP/Name of my computer by running the app on the device and setting it in the Dev Settings there...)

Official Documentation:

- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html

UPDATE 1: Here is some relevant reading with regards to configuring the `debug_http_host` device preference.

- [Issue 2727 with possible workaround - configuring via code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2727)
- [Issue 1429 with iOS specific workaround](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1429)
- [Pull request 1546 that should have made this configurable but was never accepted](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/1546)
- [Product Pains complaint to make this configurable](https://productpains.com/post/react-native/allow-packager-port-to-be-configurable-change-from-8081/)

Answer (score 1):

Spent several days trying to boost the speed of this emulator and finally got everything working very fast and smooth.

You need to have the latest version of node. If it's out of date it will be monstrously slow.

Now, if you find yourself having to close the node server and re-run "react-native run android" after every little change you make, then your "file watcher" is never being instatiated. In order to make the file watcher start up, you should: (1)Edit  yourAwesomeApp\node_modules\react-native\packager\react-packager\src\node-haste\FileWatcher\index.js (2) and change MAX_WAIT_TIME to a larger value (like 600000). Node will only wait for filewatcher to start up for this amount of time, so if the value is too low node just skips over it and continues fetching the bundle. With the file watcher going, you can simply double tap R to reload the little changes to code you make.

Now, you will need to be able to see all your console.log(). In order to do that in Genymotion (the emulator that I recommend, even free one) press ctrl M with your app running and click 'Debug JS Remotely'. That will open a tab in your web browser (http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui). Inspect this page to bring up the console!

Answer (score 0):

there have two way download js bundle from metro server:

use adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 forward local tcp port to computer tcp port ,so use usb-line you can download js-bundle from computer extremely fast.
defect : you must have use-line and adb env setup
advantage : fast download and not not need let your phone and computer on same LAN

set debug server host to 192.168.x.xxx:8081 in your application,
so you can download js-bundle from remote computer without use-line connect
defect : js-bundle can be download slowly when WIFI connect is slow
advantage : you can download js-bundle from any computer in same LAN