# Fetching js bundle react native never ending

Tags: javascript, android, ios, android-studio, react-native

I'm trying to run my first react native app.

I'm stuck in the fetching JS bundle screen forever. I went to christmas dinner with my family and when I came back the screen was still there so my guess is, t will stay like this for quite a while :(.

I'm currently on a pretty old device. I have 6 GB ram and Intel 2,4 GHz processor. I did all the stuff explained in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content. I'm firing the app on Nexus 5 mobile. Do you guys know how can I fix this?

I cant put images yet so heres the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAEg6.png

Comment: try to restart react-native packager and try once more

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some older computers might have problem starting react native app. I tried firing some react native app on a newer computer and it worked just fine.
This would kind of make sense considering a lot of people reported having long loading times for example here ["Fetching JS Bundle" Monstrously Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958376/fetching-js-bundle-monstrously-slow/40453033#40453033).